# 'brew install cmake' gives 'InsecurePlatformWarning'

Tags: cmake, homebrew, osx-mavericks

on mac OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

```
 $brew install cmake
```

gives

```
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://cmake.org/files/v3.8/cmake-3.8.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake-3.8.0.tar.gz
==> ./bootstrap --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.0 --no-system-libs --parallel=8 --datadir=/share/cmake --docdir=/sh
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/me/Library/Logs/Homebrew/cmake/02.make:
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/ctest
[100%] Built target ctest
Scanning dependencies of target documentation
[100%] sphinx-build man: see Utilities/Sphinx/build-man.log

Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.5.5/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/util/requests.py", line 52, in <module>
    requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecurePlatformWarning)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InsecurePlatformWarning'
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-FKTGTI.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
make[2]: *** [Utilities/Sphinx/doc_format_man] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/Sphinx/CMakeFiles/documentation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

These open issues may also help:
glew 2.0.0: add "--with-cmake" option https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/12722
qt5: cmake find_package(Qt5Core) doesn't work when linked to /usr/local https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/8392

Error: You are using macOS 10.9.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

Error: You are using macOS 10.9.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

why am i getting this error?
A search for this on SO led me to [this](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) page which says 'This happens on Python 2 platforms that have an outdated ssl module. '

I am using Python 2.7.13. I followed [this](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2) page and issued:

```
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

turns out make 3.8 is not compatible w mavericks. i upgraded to el capitan and it installed without a hiccough.